# Simple check operation is not working in java

Tags: java

```
String TypedMaxNumber = MaxValue.getText();
if(TypedMaxNumber == "100")
    System.out.println(TypedMaxNumber+" = 100");
```

I think it is a silly problem, but when I am running to run this program and I type 100 in the text Field it is not going inside the loop. What could be the reason.

Comment: Don't use == to compare String(s), use equals(String) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running to run this program and I type 100 in the text Field it
>   is not going inside the loop.

Its

```
if(TypedMaxNumber.equals("100"))
```

Since `TypedMaxNumber` is of type `String`. `equals()` check for value equality

Comment: Thanks it totally solve the problem..